# Running Total in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a query related to Running Total in SQl. I try to calculate the running total and put the data in temp table. Then source the data but it shows multiple months not the aggregate one

```
use tempdb

SELECT
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(7),PGLD,126) AS PMONTH,
    CLN,
    DIN,
    MAN,
    SUM(ALID) OVER (ORDER BY PGLD ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS CUMULATIVE_ALID,
    ALID
    into #1
FROM tempdb.dbo."AT"
GROUP BY
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(7),PGLD,126),
    PGLD,
    CLN,
    DIN,
    MAN,
    ALID;

SELECT PMONTH, CUMULATIVE_ALID FROM #1``
```

Please help how to get the data

Comment: Can you add sample data and expected result

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you working on?

Comment: @TT. Definitely `2012+`

Comment: Remove PGLD column From GROUP BY Clause

Answer (score 0):

You don't need GROUP BY on PGLD.

```
use tempdb

SELECT
  CONVERT(VARCHAR(7),PGLD,126) AS PMONTH,
    CLN,
    DIN,
    MAN,
    SUM(ALID) OVER (ORDER BY PGLD ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS CUMULATIVE_ALID,
    ALID
    into #1
FROM tempdb.dbo."AT"
GROUP BY
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(7),PGLD,126),
    PGLD,
    CLN,
    DIN,
    MAN,
    ALID;

SELECT PMONTH, CUMULATIVE_ALID FROM #1
```

Comment: Thanks sir for the reply.. If I am removing the PGLD in Group by Clause it shows an error.

Comment: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
Column 'tempdb.dbo.AT.PGLD' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: E.g of dataset:

Comment: PGLD CLN DIN MAN ALID
2014-02-01 CHIM CHNM CHCN 23
2014-02-01 CHIM CHNM NHIN 11
2014-02-01 CHIM CHNM PNN 8
2014-02-03 CHIM CHFM CHAN 1
2014-02-03 CHIM CHFM CHBN 1
2014-02-03 CHIM CHFM CHBN 3
2014-02-03 CHIM CHFM CHCN 2
2014-02-03 CHIM CHFM CHLN 1
2014-02-03 CHIM CHFM CHLFN 4
2014-02-03 CHIM CHFM CHON 1

Comment: Expected Result:

Feb 2014 -  55